# How to get attention weights from attention neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, attention-model

I have a model that uses an attention mechanism as below:

```
def create_model(feature_size, max_features, num_class):
   
    feature_input = Input((max_features,feature_size), dtype=tf.float32)
   
    feature_vectors = TimeDistributed(Dense(feature_size, use_bias=False, activation='tanh'))(feature_input)
   
    # Attention Layer
    attention_vectors = Dense(1,)(feature_vectors)
    attention_weights = Softmax()(attention_vectors)
   
    # Generating code vectors
    text_vectors = K.sum(feature_vectors * attention_weights, axis=1)
   
    # Prediction layer
    output_class = Dense(num_class, use_bias=False, activation='softmax')(text_vectors)
   
    model = Model(inputs=feature_input, outputs=output_class)
    return model
```

The training and testing codes are given below:

```
model = create_model(feature_size, max_features, num_class)
#compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                       optimizer='adam',
                       metrics=['acc'])
# check summary of model
model.summary()
 
# Early stopping
earlystopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor ="val_loss",
                                    mode ="min", patience = 20,
                                    restore_best_weights = True)
 
# train model
model.fit(x=X_train, y=Y_train,batch_size=64,epochs=200,validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), callbacks =[earlystopping])
 
# Performance
predicted = model.predict(x=X_test)
```

Here, the input has the dimension (**batch_size, max_feature, feature_size**). **max_feature** is the number of features for a given input and each feature is a vector of **feature_size** length. After that, I have calculated attention weights for each feature which is later used to calculate one single vector (**text_vectors**) with a weighted sum using these attention weights (**feature_vectors X attention weights**). After training the model, I want to have the attention weights for each test data point which were used to calculate the **text_vector** for that test data input. How can I achieve that?

I have already seen several SO posts such as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49129858/how-to-extract-weights-of-hidden-layers-with-keras-api), one single line of code is being used.

```
weights = [layer.get_weights() for layer in model.layers]
```

But, I am confused about how to put that in my code and how to get these attention weights for each feature for a given test data point. Can anyone please give me any direction?

Comment: I looks like you need the output of the softmax for each test sample (attention scores)? and not the weights of the attention mechanism? Because the attention weights are same for any input.

Comment: @vijayachandranmariappan, Yes, you are right. I need the output of the softmax for each test sample (attention scores). How can I get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a subset of the model which just outputs the `attention scores`:

```
attention = keras.Model(inputs=model.input, 
                                 outputs=model.get_layer("softmax").output)
```

and run,

```
 attention.predict(X_test)
```

Also make sure the layer name is proper in `model.get_layer("softmax')`. You can check by:

```
for layer in model.layers:
    print(layer.name)
```

Comment: I have tried your approach but I got 1 for all my features. You can check here https://ibb.co/2FppD7h. I got array([[1.],[1.],[1.],[1.]], dtype=float32) for attention_weight[0] when attention_weight = attention.predict(X_test). Shouldn't the array return some probability which would sum as 1 instead of each element in the array as 1? What am I missing here?

Comment: your dense output size is `Dense(1,)` is 1, thats why you always get softmax as 1, because you are applying softmax on that dimension.

Comment: I have the outputs of the dense layer before the softmax layer. So, there are four values for the four different features. I used the softmax layer to convert these values into the 0-1 range. But the softmax layer gives only 1’s for all the features. Can you please check this document (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VDAnhnGSiN04_A_ObEZlo-PSPKpP3_RCRiGEqJNCkAg/edit?usp=sharing). I have put more information there. What is the reason for this to happen? How can I get the attention scores for each feature?

Comment: tf.nn.softmax([[-0.1732]]) is 1. You are not applying softmax on the 4 values, but you are applying it on individual values. Remove the softmax activation from the Dense layer and then add tf.nn.softmax applied on the proper dimension after the dense layer.

Answer (score -5):

it is possible but you don't need to create complex classes or functions for understanding it is just the multiplication of inputs and learning weights.

> Sample: INT is significant !!!

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_text as tft

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn.metrics
from sklearn.svm import SVC

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
input_word = tf.constant(' \'Cause it\'s easy as an ice cream sundae Slipping outta your hand into the dirt Easy as an ice cream sundae Every dancer gets a little hurt Easy as an ice cream sundae Slipping outta your hand into the dirt Easy as an ice cream sundae Every dancer gets a little hurt Easy as an ice cream sundae Oh, easy as an ice cream sundae ')
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors( tf.strings.bytes_split(input_word) )
print( dataset )

window_size = 6
vocab = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "I", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "_" ]
layer = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=vocab)
ZeroPadding1D = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding1D(padding=(2))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Class and Functions
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_outputs):
        super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs
        
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
        shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
        self.num_outputs])

    def call(self, inputs):
    
        inputs_vocab = tf.constant( tf.cast( layer( inputs ), dtype=tf.float32 ), shape=(1, 6, 1) )
        Zero_padding = tf.constant( ZeroPadding1D( inputs_vocab ), shape=(10, 1) )
        
        print( inputs )
        print( Zero_padding )

        softmax = tf.keras.layers.Softmax( axis=-1 )
        # temp = softmax( Zero_padding )
        temp = Zero_padding
        ############################################################################################
                
        clf = SVC(random_state=0)
        clf.fit(tf.constant( temp, shape=(10, 1) ).numpy(), tf.cast( tf.linspace( 0, 9, 10, name='linspace', axis=0 ), dtype=tf.int64 ).numpy())
        predictions = clf.predict(tf.constant( temp, shape=(10, 1) ).numpy())
        
        cm = sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix( [temp[0], temp[1], temp[2], temp[3], temp[4], temp[5], temp[6], temp[7], temp[8], temp[9]], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], labels=clf.classes_)
        disp = sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm, display_labels=clf.classes_)
        disp.plot()
        plt.show()
        ############################################################################################
        
        return temp

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Datasets
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tft.sliding_window(x, width=window_size, axis=0)).flat_map(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Tasks
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
layer_dense = MyDenseLayer(10)
for sample in dataset:
    result = layer_dense( sample )
    print(result)
```

> Output:

```
tf.Tensor([b"'" b'C' b'a' b'u' b's' b'e'], shape=(6,), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(
[[ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 1.]
 [21.]
 [19.]
 [ 5.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]], shape=(10, 1), dtype=float32)
```

[image: Sample]